# Providing input for while loop

Tags: scripts

```
while getopts "f:t:d:g:o:p:b:q:r:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in

(f)fan=${OPTARG}
(t)..
 esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));
```

How to provide input?
Can anyone plz tell me how to provide input for the above mentioned code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular while loop (using `getopts`) you would usually put it in a *shell script* and then call the script with your options/argument(s) e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "f:t:d:g:o:p:b:q:r:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in

  f) fan=${OPTARG}
  ;;
  t) echo "doing somthing with option t = $OPTARG"
  ;;
 esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));
```

then make it executable

```
chmod +x yourscript.sh
```

then run it as

```
$ ./yourscript.sh -t 3
doing somthing with option t = 3
```